# Is there any heuristic/pattern for logging user actions

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I have a GWT/Java/Hibernate/MySQL application (but I think any web pattern could be valid) that do a CRUD on several objects. Each object is stored in a table in the database. I want to implement an action logger. For example for Object A I want to know who created it and modified it, and for User B, what actions did he perform.

My idea is to have a History table that stores : UserId, ObjectId, ActionName. The UserId and ObjectId are foreign keys. Am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think this is the right direction. 
However, bare in mind that in an application with lots of traffic, this logs can become overhead.
I would suggest the following in this case - 
A. Don't use hibernate for this "action logging" - Hibernate has better performance for "mostly read DB" 
B. Consider DB that is better in "mostly write" scenario for the action logging table. 
You can try to look for a NoSQL solution for this. 
C. If you use such NoSQL DB, but still want to keep the logging actions in the relational DB, have an offline process that runs once in a day for example), that will query your "action logging DB" and will insert it to the relational DB. 
D. If it's ok that your system might lose some action logging, consider using producer/consumer pattern (for example - use a queue between producer and consumer thread) - the threads that need to log actions will not log them synchronously, but will log them asynchronously. 
E. In addition, don't forget that such logging table has the potential to be over-flooded in time, causing queries on it to take a long time. 
 For these issues consider the following: 
E.1. Every day remove really old logs - let's say - older than month, or move them to some "backup" table. 
E.2 Index some fields that you mostly use for action logging queries (for example - maybe an action_type) field.

Comment: Accepted for the asynchronous logging

Answer (score 1):

If only changes to specific fields, e.g., something like status in a users table, should be tracked, I would use a user_status_histories table being referenced from the users table via foreign key. The user_status_histories table would contain fields such as current_status, date and something like admin_who_modified_the_status.

Whenever a status change is made, a new record would be inserted into the user_status_histories table. This would allow easy querying of all status changes.

Of course, querying a user would then require a (LEFT or INNER) JOIN with the user_status_histories table in order to get the last record (= the current status).

Depending on your needs, you might think of a current_status field in the users table (besides the status serving as foreign key) for fast access, which would be maintained parallel to the user_status_histories table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are.  Another very similar framework is one which supports undo and redo.  These frameworks track user actions and have the additional ability to restore state to the way it was before the user action.

Comment: It sounds interesting...can you please name some examples for Java ?

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be the user access logs for a web application that show user, url requested, http verb and time of day.  Those are written to log files and not data bases because of the huge vole of data, but when doing a log analysis those logs are read into a database much like what you've described above.

Comment: In my case the user's actions doesn't necessarily have an URL because I'am using RPC kind of request

Comment: True, but you asked for similar examples.  I'm assuming that your business requirements a driving you to do this and so there are specifics that apply only to you.